# HCE (Host card emulation) in my payment application opening default payment apps in Nexus 6P(OS version: 8.1) but working in Sony(OS: 6.0)

Tags: android

I implemented HCE (Host card emulation) for my application. When am trying to communicate with payment terminal it is working in Sony (6.0) but it is opening a default app even though i set (Except when another payment app is open) in tap and pay section in Nexus 6P (OS : 8.1).  Can anyone please help me with this. Why is it working fine in one phone and not in another? I can't even see my application in tap and pay section in Nexus 6P (OS : 8.1). Do I have to add any additional code in OS: 8.1 ?

```
 My code: (I used this code from the different post in StackOverflow but it doesn't have ans for my problem)



    Following code is returning false for the app.

    boolean isDefault = CardEmulation
                    .getInstance(NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this))
                    .isDefaultServiceForCategory(
                            new ComponentName(this, MyPaymentService.class),
                            CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT);

    Service declaration in manifest:

    <service
        android:name="my.package.MyPaymentService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE"/>               

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>

    apduservice:

    <host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:requireDeviceUnlock="true" >

        <aid-group
            android:category="payment"
            android:description="@string/paymentGroup" >
            <aid-filter
                android:name="A0000000041010"
                android:description="@string/mastercard" />
            <aid-filter
                android:name="A0000000031010"
                android:description="@string/visa" />
            <aid-filter
                android:name="A000000003101001"
                android:description="@string/visa" />
            <aid-filter
                android:name="A0000002771010"
                android:description="@string/interac" />
        </aid-group>

    </host-apdu-service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer from a similar thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789858

It mentiones additional entries in manifest that must be present to show your app in tap&pay menu:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```